# Cut a part from a linked list?

Tags: java, performance, linked-list

can I cut (delete) a portion from a Linked List by index?
For example, if the input is "100", I want to delete the first 100 elements
from a linked list. Currently, my code deletes them one by one.

```
public void remove(LinkedList<String> queue, int count){
    if (count > queue.size()) {
        System.out.println(ERROR);
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        queue.remove(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: No, there is no shortcut here - you must traverse the list to find the 100th element, so the time complexity is the same. You could skip deletion of every node and simply join the root the element 101 though.

Answer (score 0):

you try with this:

```
splitList =  queue.subList(0, 100);
```

Comment: Will that be faster?

Comment: subList returns List, not LinkedList. I can't cast it.

Comment: In what way does that *"**delete** the first 100 elements"*, as requested in the question?

Comment: The problem is that I need to remove the elements faster than one by one.

Answer (score 0):

To delete the first 100 elements of a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html), whether [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html), or any other kind of mutable list:

```
list.subList(0, 100).clear();
```

This is documented in the javadoc of [`subList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-):

> This method eliminates the need for explicit range operations (of the sort that commonly exist for arrays). Any operation that expects a list can be used as a range operation by passing a subList view instead of a whole list. For example, the following idiom removes a range of elements from a list:
>
> ```
> list.subList(from, to).clear();
> ```